# I just need one line for the output "the car has 6 doors"(the one with more doors).But the output will give as many (lines) doors as added to the code

Tags: java, class, output

```
package Car;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.AddDoor();
        myCar.AddDoor();
    }

}

class Car {
    public int door = 4;
    
    public void AddDoor() {
        this.door++;
        System.out.println("The car has   " + door + " " + "doors");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't have I/O code in the Car class but rather in the main class. In other words, get the println statement ***out*** of the `addDoor()` method. Instead, give Car a `public int getDoor()` method and call it in Main after adding doors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is to *add* doors without *printing* anything about the doors. The code you posted is doing both in one method: `this.door++` as well as `System.out.println()`. Instead, you need two different methods. Here's a way to edit what you posted to work like you want.

1. Remove the `System.out.println()` from `addDoor()` (notice the lowercase first letter, that follows Java naming conventions). As you noted, you want to add a door without printing anything about the door totals. That would leave your method looking like this:

   ```
   public void addDoor() {
       this.door++;
   }
   ```
2. Make a new method in your `Car` class, call it `printDoorInfo()` or some such, and move your `println()` code there, like this:

   ```
   public void printDoorInfo() {
       System.out.println("The car has " + this.door + " doors");
   }
   ```
3. In your calling code, after you have called `myCar.addDoor()` as many times as you like, call your new door info printer:

   ```
   myCar.printDoorInfo();
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much my friend, it was really useful, I really appreciate it. It worked after following your instructions